# How can I throw error in onNext() with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

```
.subscribe(
    new Action1<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Response response) {
            if (response.isSuccess())
            //handle success
            else
            //throw an Throwable(reponse.getMessage())
        }
    },
    new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            //handle Throwable throw from onNext();
        }
    }
);
```

I don't wanna handle `(!response.isSuccess())` in `onNext()`. How can I throw it to `onError()` and handle with other throwable together?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `FailureException extends RuntimeException`, then

```
.doOnNext(response -> {
  if(!response.isSuccess())
    throw new FailureException(response.getMessage());
})
.subscribe(
    item  -> { /* handle success */ },
    error -> { /* handle failure */ }
);
```

This works best if you throw the exception as early as possible, as then you can do retries, alternative responses etc. easily.

Comment: Don't exceptions that extend RuntimeException when thrown crash as they are not handled by RxJava?

Answer (score 15):

you can `flatMap` your response to Response or Error

```
flatMap(new Func1<Response, Observable<Response>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Response> call(Response response) {
        if(response.isSuccess()){
            return Observable.just(response);
        } else {
            return Observable.error(new Throwable(response.getMessage()));
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add an operator in the middle. My suggestion is to use `map` as it does not generate new `Observable` object (in comparison to `flatMap` which does it):

```
.map(new Func1<Response, Response>() {
    @Override
    public Response call(Response response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            return response;
        } else {
            throw new Throwable(reponse.getMessage()));
        }
    }
 })
```

Comment: FYI: map does create a new observable object it just does it for you internally.